# placeholder disappears after changing margin between inputs

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I have a form in a Landing Page. I just wanted to change the margin between inputs:

This is what I have now:

[image]

I want to achieve this result:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<input class="input-form-catalogue" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name*" required>
<input class="input-form-catalogue" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email*" required>
      <div class="row">
             <div class="col-6">
                    <select name="country" title="country*" class="select-country-form-catalogue selectpicker text-center">
                        @include('includes.options-country')
                     </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6" style="padding-right:7.5px;padding-left: 2px;">
                     <input class="input-form-catalogue" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="phone*" required>
              </div>
     </div>
```

These are the classes:

```
.input-form-catalogue {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.7rem;
        border: 0.1px solid #7B7B79;
        background: transparent;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

.select-country-form-catalogue {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.55rem;
        border: 0.1px solid #7B7B79;
        background: transparent;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        text-align: center;
        color: #7B7B79;
    }
```

I just simply wanted to change the margin attribute on the css classes. So I changed them to:

```
margin: 0.5rem 0;
```

But after doing that the placeholders on the text input dissapear. I have no idea why:

[image]

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please create a codepen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding another class called "press" to each text input, then I changed the CSS to:

```
.input-form-catalogue.press {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.7rem;
        border: 0.1px solid #7B7B79;
        background: transparent;
        margin: 0.5rem 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```